# tableview in normal view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am doing the project which need to use the storyboard to rewrite the old project. I got some problems when I doing it use the storyboard. I use the normal view controller instead of tableview controller, because there are some buttons and labels in this view controller. The problem is I don't know how to link between this view controller and the detail view controller when users select the cell from the table view.

Comment: Do you want to do it in Storyboard or in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply drag the tableview to a normal VC.

ctrl+drag from your table to the orange circle below to connect as delegate/datasource.

make your VC to implement uitableview delegate and datasource protocols (`@interface MyVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`).

write the mandatory protocol methods:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:function1DetailViewController animated:YES];

Comment: should i need to write the prepareForSegue method?

Comment: if you segue using storyboard (ctrl+drag) yes you have to. an alternative is to implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I don't know how to write the prepareForSegue method. Actually the i have the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 NSString *tempSqlStatement = @"";
 NSString *tempString = @"%";
 databaseName = @"TCMdb8.sql";
 NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
 (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
 databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
     databaseName];
if(){⋯⋯}

Comment: function1SQLStatement = [tempSqlStatement UTF8String];
        
        [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
        [self readFromDatabase];
        [tableList reloadData];
        buttonNum = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Select a cell in the Table View. And make a segue to the `DetailViewController` by ctrl clicking on the Table Cell and dragging to the `DetailViewController` in the Storyboard.
Then select a segue type based on the type of transition you want: modal, or push (if these view controllers are embedded in a navigation controller, etc.)

Comment: If I don't have table cell in my table view, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use following code:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[YourNewViewControllerClass new] animated:YES];
```